# Petición POST en Laravel mediante POSTMAN

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy aprendiendo Laravel y me ha surgido una duda con un proyecto que he visto en [Github](https://github.com/uF4No/passport-api-demo), se trata de una aplicación con Laravel Passport y Vue, el registro y el login dentro de la aplicación funcionan bien, pero al hacer una petición POST en Postman a /login, me devuelve `419`, he probado a pasar el token csrf y las cookies pero me sigue devolviendo lo mismo.

Creo que es debido a las rutas.

```
// Auth protected routes
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group( function(){
  Route::get('/tasks', 'Api\TaskController@index')->name('api.tasks');
  Route::post('/tasks', 'Api\TaskController@store')->name('api.tasks.store');
  Route::post('/tasks/{id}/complete', 'Api\TaskController@complete')->name('api.tasks.complete');
  
});
```

He pensado que debido al middleware, postman no puede hacer la petición asi que he añadido la siguiente ruta pero sigue sin funcionar.

```
Route::post('/login', 'Api\LoginController@login');
```

**ACTUALIZADO**

Ya he encontrado el problema, en el form se manda un input hidden con el token sin encriptar.

Para solucionarlo hay que hacer una petición GET antes del POST y conseguir el `_token` del input, al mandarselo en el POST ya funciona todo correctamente.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo todo a la vez?, he estado mirando lo de los test para coger automáticamente el `token`, pero no he visto ninguna manera de hacer la petición POST y que antes de eso coja el `token`

Comment: ese error suele ser debido a la falta de token csrf. Cuando haces la peticion tienes añadido en las cabeceras `_token`? puede ser eso o algo relacionado...

Comment: Si lo he añadido, también he probado a poner login en las excepciones del csrf pero sigue pasando lo mismo

Answer (score 1):

Te falta el token de Passport. No es necesario el CSRF ya que es una API. En este caso debe ser uno de tipo Bearer

[Passing The Access Token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#passing-the-access-token)

Comment: No me queda muy claro como funciona este proyecto, en Postman no me parece que este accediendo a una api, necesita las cookies y el csrf del input. Basicamente es como si hiciera el login en la web, como podría añadir las rutas necesarias para la api, y donde consigo el Access Token, por lo que he visto serviría para autorizar el acceso a la API.